# ElasticSearch/Kibana not showing time in IST format when pushing data from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

Below is my code in which i am trying to push data to my elasticsearch from my python script. Data is getting inserted just fine but one small problem is when i use kibana then it shows time in UTC format rather in IST format. How do i fix this.

```
import time
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(['122.15.1.12'])
port=9200

ltime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

es.index(index='xdist', doc_type='threads', body={
'supplier': qantas[d],
'date': ltime,
'threadcount': ActiveThreads
                })
```

Comment: are you refering @timestamp  ?

Comment: In Kibana -5 you can achiceve this by Go to Settings > Advanced.
Click the Edit button for the option you want to modify.  dateFormat:tz
The timezone that Kibana uses. The default value of Browser uses the timezone detected by the browser.

Comment: @Backtrack - I tried that. It did'nt work. I changed the time to  Asia/Calcutta but still i am getting time in UST format

Comment: Doesn't `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` produce a string with the time of the server use are running this script from? You may just put a datetime struck to ES client so it will be thought as a date (not a scring) by Kibana